Create column of current balance in PySpark
I have the below dataframe created in PySpark code:
+---------------+-------------+---------------+------+
|TransactionDate|AccountNumber|TransactionType|Amount|
+---------------+-------------+---------------+------+
|     2023-01-01|          100|         Credit|  1000|
|     2023-01-02|          100|         Credit|  1500|
|     2023-01-03|          100|          Debit|  1000|
|     2023-01-02|          200|         Credit|  3500|
|     2023-01-03|          200|          Debit|  2000|
|     2023-01-04|          200|         Credit|  3500|
|     2023-01-13|          300|         Credit|  4000|
|     2023-01-14|          300|          Debit|  4500|
|     2023-01-15|          300|         Credit|  5000|
+---------------+-------------+---------------+------+

I need to print another column as CurrentBalance.
Expected output:
+---------------+-------------+---------------+------+--------------+
|TransactionDate|AccountNumber|TransactionType|Amount|CurrentBalance|
+---------------+-------------+---------------+------+--------------+
|     2023-01-01|          100|         Credit|  1000|          1000|
|     2023-01-02|          100|         Credit|  1500|          2500|
|     2023-01-03|          100|          Debit|  1000|          1500|
|     2023-01-02|          200|         Credit|  3500|          3500|
|     2023-01-03|          200|          Debit|  2000|          1500|
|     2023-01-04|          200|         Credit|  3500|          5000|
|     2023-01-13|          300|         Credit|  4000|          4000|
|     2023-01-14|          300|          Debit|  4500|          -500|
|     2023-01-15|          300|         Credit|  5000|          1000|
+---------------+-------------+---------------+------+--------------+

I have tried with min date and passing the date in when condition to calculate the credit and debit, but it seems not working.
# Find minimum date in TransactionDate column, grouped by AccountNumber column
df_new.groupBy('AccountNumber').agg(f.min('TransactionDate').alias('min_date'))


You will need a window function for this. Window functions do calculations for every row in a partition (group). In this case, you need to sum all the values row-after-row.
Also, simple sum would not work, as you do not have negative numbers, so you must make them using input from column "TransactionType".
Example data:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('2023-01-01', '100', 'Credit', 1000),
     ('2023-01-02', '100', 'Credit', 1500),
     ('2023-01-03', '100', 'Debit', 1000),
     ('2023-01-02', '200', 'Credit', 3500),
     ('2023-01-03', '200', 'Debit', 2000),
     ('2023-01-04', '200', 'Credit', 3500),
     ('2023-01-13', '300', 'Credit', 4000),
     ('2023-01-14', '300', 'Debit', 4500),
     ('2023-01-15', '300', 'Credit', 5000)],
    ['TransactionDate', 'AccountNumber', 'TransactionType', 'Amount'])

Script:
sign = F.when(F.col('TransactionType') == 'Debit', -1).otherwise(1)
amount = sign * F.col('amount')
window = W.partitionBy('AccountNumber').orderBy('TransactionDate')

df = df.withColumn('CurrentBalance', F.sum(amount).over(window))

df.show() 
# +---------------+-------------+---------------+------+--------------+
# |TransactionDate|AccountNumber|TransactionType|Amount|CurrentBalance|
# +---------------+-------------+---------------+------+--------------+
# |     2023-01-01|          100|         Credit|  1000|          1000|
# |     2023-01-02|          100|         Credit|  1500|          2500|
# |     2023-01-03|          100|          Debit|  1000|          1500|
# |     2023-01-02|          200|         Credit|  3500|          3500|
# |     2023-01-03|          200|          Debit|  2000|          1500|
# |     2023-01-04|          200|         Credit|  3500|          5000|
# |     2023-01-13|          300|         Credit|  4000|          4000|
# |     2023-01-14|          300|          Debit|  4500|          -500|
# |     2023-01-15|          300|         Credit|  5000|          4500|
# +---------------+-------------+---------------+------+--------------+


Wonderful, Thanks for your valuable advice. @ZygD
